# How to notify Property grid collection propery change

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a wpf application and im using winform host.
In some cases the 'SelectedItem' property is complex type that have a property from type 'List'.
How can i know from code if the collection changed? Or just know of the custom editor opened?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List` to have the functionality of indicating changes to the contents of the list.

The ObservableCollection implements the interfaces `INotifyCollectionChanged` and 
`INotifyPropertyChanged` to archive this behaviour.

More information to ObservableCollection on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The selected object can be user custom class so i cant control the 'collection' type.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you have collection of elements, and each of them have some other collection. 
In that way you could also consider using [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as your base collection - it implements`IRaiseItemChangedEvents` - `Indicates whether a class converts property change events to System.ComponentModel.IBindingList.ListChanged`

Comment: The selected object can be user custom class so i cant control the 'collection' type.